# C backslash newline in the middle of word emits error

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

The GNU CPP says about backslash new lines

> A continued line is a line which ends with a backslash, ‘\’. The backslash is removed and the following line is joined with the current one. No space is inserted, so you may split a line anywhere, even in the middle of a word. (It is generally more readable to split lines only at white space.)

When I compile the following, breaking the `printf` word I get an error like:

> error: unknown type name 'prin'

```c
// Online C compiler https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    prin\
    tf("Hello world");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why are the lines not joined together?

Answer (score 2):

The lines are joined together. However, as the second line starts with indent, you end up with `prin tf`. Remove all leading white space on the line with `tf`, and it will compile.